# Is subsumption architecture still an active area of research?

Tags: control, research

I am interested in learning more about [subsumption architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsumption_architecture). I have read a number of books that talk about the idea but none of them go into great detail. I have also read a fair number of Dr. Brooks papers on the topic however he hasn't published much on the topic in recent years.

Is this still an active area of research? Are there are any must read papers on the topic?

Comment: Given the [discussion on meta](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/91/37), I have tried to make the question a little less localised rather than voting to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you probably guessed from the lack of answers, subsumption architecture is not an active area of research any more. Most papers on this have been published in the late 80's / early 90's.

This doesn't mean that subsumption architecture is dead; it has been very influential in robotics, and it's still used in education for example, but it is just not a hot topic in research any more.

Comment: Is SA still used in any commercial robotic applications ?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, the only current commercial application that comes to mind is the Roomba. Even Baxter from Rethink Robotics (Brook's current company) seems to work in a more conventional way.

Comment: @Theran, would you care to expand that into an answer? I didn't realise Roomba used SA for instance.

Comment: Is there a reason why it "died"?  What led to its current lack of scientific inquiry?